# Adding style to active link?

Tags: css

Hi at my site [website](http://marctesting.myshopify.com/) (password: ebriff) i have added small white triangles as pictures to the active link. But since i have a picture as my first menu link, it won't get added to that. How do I get around this?

CSS:

```
.top-menu li{
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff; /* text color */
    font-size: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,1,.5); /* drop shadow */
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 300;
  } 

li.top {
    border-right: 1px solid #007472;
    border-left: 1px solid #009C9A;
}

li.top:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

li.top:first-child {
    width: 70px;
    border-left: none;
    background: url({{'home-icon.png'|asset_url}}) no-repeat 24px 25px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.current {
    background: url({{'triangle.png'|asset_url}}) no-repeat center bottom}
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show us your HTML too.

Comment: Um... you sure it's safe to include that password in this publicly-visible website you don't own or control?

Comment: If the password isn't sensitive, and you'll be changing it later, that link will rot and the question will not be relevant in the future.

Comment: Please try to minimize your CSS as much as possible when you post a question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the home icon as background image for the link instead of the list item. At least this worked for me when I tried it in chrome developer tools ;)
So instead of

```
li.top:first-child {
  width: 70px;
  border-left: none;
  background: url({{'home-icon.png'|asset_url}}) no-repeat 24px 25px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

use

```
li.top:first-child {
  width: 70px;
  border-left: none;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
li.top:first-child a{
  background: url({{'home-icon.png'|asset_url}}) no-repeat 24px 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use CSS3 multiple backgrounds

```
background: url(...), url(...);
```

or you may manually create an image with arrow overlayed over the "normal background icon" and use it for the :active selector. 
Consider using CSS sprites as well.

On multiple backgrounds: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: I tried adding this:
.current {
  background: url({{'home-icon.png'|asset_url}}) no-repeat 24px 25px, background: url({{'triangle.png'|asset_url}}) no-repeat center bottom};
}

Comment: But then it stopped working on all of them. But at the same time if it worked, the home icon would also be added to all of different links right?

Comment: in your code, the second background-declaration _overwrites_ the first one instead of _adding_ to it. please write: background: url(...) no-repeat 24px 25px, url(...) no-repeat center bottom;

Comment: use two rules: one for .current, and one for .current:first-child